# issue when i try to connect two columns by a third columns

Tags: networkx

I have a csv file that have the following:

| id_1 | id_2 | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FD345 | MER3345 | 06/12/2020 |

i want to connect id_1 -> id_2

the edge between them should be the date see the below pic

[image]

see id_1 it have a direct connected edge to id_2

the edge between them should be the date

so what i did is something like that:

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source = "id_1", target = "id_2", edge_attr='date', create_using=nx.DiGraph())
```

but in this way it did not connect the node_1 and node_2 by date it give only the attributes to be date!!

or i am not understanding correctly because the output if i did like this when i print G.edges()

```
('UCU6lC', 'vOGN5A'), ........
```

it connect the nodes but i am not sure if it connected with the date or not!

Thank you for clear out something to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [draw_networkx_edge_labels()](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable//reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edge_labels.html) to draw edge labels.

```py
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'id_1': ['FD345'],
                   'id_2': ['MER3345'],
                   'date': ['06/12/2020']
                   })

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source="id_1", target="id_2", create_using=nx.DiGraph())

nx.draw_networkx(G)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, nx.spring_layout(G), edge_labels=dict(zip(G.edges, df['date'].tolist())),
                             verticalalignment='center_baseline')

plt.show()
```

[image]